# Was ist der Unterschied zwischen Genitiv und Nomenkompositum?

Tags: difference, genitive, compound

Manchmal können wir Genitiv durch ein Nomenkompositum (und umgekehrt) ersetzen.

> die Tür des Hauses
>
> die Haustür

1. Gibt es einen semantischen Unterschied zwischen den beiden Formulierungen? Nach meinem Sprachgefühl betonen wir das Bezugswort, wenn wir Genitiv benutzen. Das Nomenkompositum klingt aber neutral.
2. Kann man immer im Falle von `Nomen + Nomen` eine Form in die andere umschreiben?

Comment: i.A. ist ein Kompositum durch den Genitiv ersetzbar. Manchmal aber nicht. Das ist ein Riesenproblem ;)

Comment: Vor der Fragenbeantwortung esse ich ein Brot der Wurst des Metts der Zwiebel …

Answer (score 4):

Punkt 1 würde ich im allgemeinen zustimmen - die getrennte Form betont die Art der Beziehung zwischen den Bestandteilen des Kompositums.

Allerdings sind nicht alle Nomen-Nomen Komposita über den Genitiv verknüpft. Hundefutter ist nicht von vornherein das Futter eines spezifischen Hundes und auch nicht das Futter der/aller Hunde - es ist Futter für Hunde.

Auch bei der Haustür ist Vorsicht geboten - "die Tür des Hauses" ist üblicherweise auch die Haustür, das trifft jedoch nicht auf alle Türen eines Hauses zu. Darüber hinaus ist "Haustür" auch die Bezeichnung für eine Kategorie von Bauformen von Türen, z.B. als Produktbezeichnung im Baumarkt. In diesen Fällen ist eine getrennte Umschreibung nicht so einfach.

Es gibt noch viele Beispiele. Ein Dampfschiff ist weder ein "Schiff des Dampfs" noch ein "Schiff für Dampf", sondern ein Schiff, dessen Antrieb mit Dampf(-maschinen) erfolgt.

Comment: Zustimm - und ein Kernkraftwerk sollte man eher nicht als "Werk der Kraft des Kerns" unschreiben...

Comment: Deine "Nicht-Beispiele" sind ein bißchen fragwürdig. Warum *Hundefutter* nicht das "Futter des Hundes" sein soll, erschließt sich mir nicht. Nimm lieber was anderes, "Sauwut", "Fegefeuer", "Schweinekälte", "Affenhitze", "Bombenstimmung" oder sowas.

Answer (score 3):

##### Eine Frage der Bestimmtheit

Beim Genitivattribut geht ohne besondere Betonung die Bestimmtheit immer vom Beschreibenden aus.
Bei "Die Tür des Hauses" ist es das Haus, das aus dem Kontext klar ist, und
bei diesem *Haus* reden wir von der *Tür*. Bildlich sucht man also erst das Haus und dann die Tür. Genauso bei "die Tür eines Hauses": Man sucht sich erst ein Haus und nimmt dann davon die Tür.

Wir haben also schon ein Haus,
damit ist es unmöglich, beim Kauf einer Haustür von "der Tür des Hauses" zu
reden, weil die Tür noch zu keinem festen Haus gehört.

Das ist auch ein Grund, warum Komposita viel mehr können als Genitivkonstruktionen.
Beim Dampfschiff zum Beispiel: Es geht nicht um einen besonderen Dampf, es ist "ein Schiff mit der Kraft des Dampfs",
wo Dampf lediglich als Konzept "der Dampf" genutzt wird.
Ein Schweineschnitzel ist "ein Schnitzel aus Schwein". Welches Schwein ist hier unwichtig.

Bei Punkt 2 haben die anderen Antworten schon viele Beispiele geliefert, wo
Komposita nicht mit Genitivkonstruktionen ersetzt werden können.

Comment: Fühlt ein Wirt sich zu Höherem berufen, steht auch gerne einmal ein "Schnitzel vom Schwein" auf der Karte

Answer (score 2):

Ein Genitivattribut drückt immer eine Zugehörigkeit aus, die entweder tatsächlich ein Besitz ist (*»der Mantel des Försters«*), oder eine besitzartige Beziehung ausdrückt.

> die Frau des Bäckers

Der Bäcker ist zwar keineswegs der Besitzer seiner Frau, aber sie gehört zu ihm. Possessivpronomen, die in den Grammatikbüchern meiner Schulzeit *»besitzanzeigende Fürwörter«* genannt wurden (**seine** Frau) drücken ebenfalls diese Art von Beziehung aus.

Ein Kompositum kann eine solche Beziehung ausdrücken (die Bäckersfrau), das ist aber nicht immer möglich.

> Der Großvater der Direktorin

Hier stehen wieder zwei Personen in einer besitzartigen Beziehung (**ihr** Großvater), aber diese Beziehung in einem Kompositum auszudrücken ist zumindest unüblich. Man wird selten von einem *»Direktorinnengroßvater«* lesen.

> Schweinsschnitzel

Dieses Kompositum drückt keine besitzartige Beziehung aus. Das Schwein besitzt das Schnitzel nicht, und es steht auch nicht in einer Beziehung zu ihm, die mit der Beziehung zwischen Personen vergleichbar ist. Daher ist *»das Schnitzel des Schweins«* falsch. Richtig ist *»das Schnitzel vom Schwein«,* weil es ja vom Schwein stammt.

> Kinderschnitzel

Hier könnte man als erste Reaktion argumentieren, dass das Kind das Schnitzel besitzt. Das ist aber erst der Fall, wenn es (oder ein Elternteil) dieses Schnitzel bestellt hat und es dann dem Kind gebracht wurde. Davor (wenn das Kind noch gar nicht im Restaurant ist) gibt es diese besitzartige Beziehung noch nicht, trotzdem stand das Kinderschnitzel schon lange davor auf der Speisekarte. Es handelt sich um ein Schnitzel, das für ein Kind bestimmt ist. Es ist daher *»ein Schnitzel für Kinder«,* nicht aber *»das Schnitzel des Kindes«.* (Letzteres ist es - wie bereits erläutert -  erst, wenn es vor dem Kind auf dem Teller liegt, nicht aber wenn es nur in der Speisekarte steht.)

Comment: Ich denke, den Genitiv als Besitzanzeiger zu verstehen ist etwas zu eng gegriffen. Der Genitivis Partitivus (_ein Großteil der Probleme_), der Genitivus Objectivus (_das Studium der Literatur_) und Genitivus Subjectivus (_Die Erfinderin des Fahrrads_) lassen sich sinnvoll vom Genitivus Possesivus differenzieren. Man _könnte_ zwar Teilhaftigkeit, Zweck und Urheberschaft als "besitzartig" auffassen, aber das hieße dann doch das Pferd von hinten aufzäumen.

Comment: Dein Schweineschnitzelbeispiel kontere ich mit Blumenduft - Da ist auch kein "Besitz" dabei, man kann aber trotzdem "der Duft der Blume" sagen. Genitiv ist viel mehr als nur  Besitz.